# Mouse stop clicking when fully loaded

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, construct-2

I made a game and I used construct 2 to build it,
I have a problem regarding the mouse clicking (outside the game) for example the user cant scroll down using the mouse (left click) only keyboard or scroll button on the mouse.

What could be the problem ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried clicking outside of canvas and then scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for this code in the file `c2runtime.js`, you should also uncheck the minify option when you export the project.

```
if (this.useMouseInput && !this.runtime.isDomFree)
    {
        jQuery(document).mousemove(
            function(info) {
                self.onMouseMove(info);
            }
        );
        jQuery(document).mousedown(
            function(info) {
                self.onMouseDown(info);
            }
        );
        jQuery(document).mouseup(
            function(info) {
                self.onMouseUp(info);
            }
        );
    }
```

And remove it